# How can I call I view inside a Web form and do a Post inside that view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to add a view inside a Web form and its fine to show data. But I do a post it break. I have used [LINK](https://clicktricity.com/2010/06/22/using-mvc-renderaction-within-a-webform/) sample which I found on sof but it wont work for POST Request. Always throwing a MAC fail error.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms typically uses a single form for the entire page. But [HTML does not support nested forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379622/181087), so if you put another form onto the page via MVC partial view, you need to ensure the partial view is not rendered inside of your `<form runat="server">` tag.

[Here is an example](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/) of using multiple forms with Webforms.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>ASP.NET web form (POST)</legend>
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtSearch">Name: </asp:Label><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" /><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSend" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSend_Click" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <form method="get" action="Search.aspx">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Regular HTML form using GET</legend>
            <label for="name-text">Name: </label><input type="text" id="name-text" name="q" /><input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="Search.aspx">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Regular HTML form using POST</legend>
            <label for="name-text2">Name: </label><input type="text" id="name-text2" name="q" /><input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> **NOTE:** If your main webforms form is declared in a master page, you will need to render your MVC form inside of a separate `ContentPlaceHolder` control so the forms are not nested.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html id="Html1" runat="server" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-rdfa-1.xsd" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body id="Body1" runat="server">
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
        <!-- form for Webforms -->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>

    <!-- placeholder for external forms -->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="OutsideOfForm" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```